# How to do routerCanDeactivate in ngrx/router?

Tags: typescript, angular, router, rxjs5, ngrx

This is how I use `routerCanDeactivate` in deprecated router:

```
import { CanDeactivate, ComponentInstruction } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

export class CallComponent implements CanDeactivate {
  routerCanDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

How to do same thing that  does in **ngrx/router**? I didn’t find any document.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right now, there is no such feature in **ngrx/router**. I created an issue on GitHub, you can track it here.

https://github.com/ngrx/router/issues/127